# HDFS complains "Resources are low on NN" and enters safemode while I have enough free space

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hdfs

I am using hadoop-2.6.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, and everything went well in my test env. But while running in the production env, my HDFS repeatedly complains about not having enough space for namenode, and HDFS has entered safemode.

> 2017-11-25 14:00:48,731 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: NameNode low on available disk space. Already in safe mode.
>
> 2017-11-25 14:00:48,731 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode is ONResources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:
>    If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
>
> 2017-11-25 14:00:53,732 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeResourceChecker: Space available on volume '/home/hadoop/.Private' is 0, which is below the configured reserved a
>   mount 104857600

But the truth is I have more than enough space

> Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> udev                              63G     0   63G   0% /dev
>
> tmpfs                             13G   33M   13G   1% /run
>
> /dev/mapper/hdfsmaster--vg-root  7.1T  1.3T  5.6T  19% /
>
> tmpfs                             63G  4.0K   63G   1% /dev/shm
>
> tmpfs                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
>
> tmpfs                             63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>
> /dev/sda2                        473M   55M  394M  13% /boot
>
> /dev/sda1                        511M  4.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
>
> /home/hadoop/.Private            7.1T  1.3T  5.6T  19% /home/hadoop

HDFS data/name directories are all in /home/hadoop directory

HDFS can be started successfully, and it's NOT in safemode at beginning. But after some time (like 5, 6 hours), even if I did not perform any operation (read / write / query ), it will complain about lacking of space and enter safemode automatically.

I have tried:

1. restart hdfs
2. restart the server
3. re-format namenode
4. change data/name folder and restart hdfs

none of the above method helps.

Please help! This is killing me!

Comment: Have you found any solution? Facing the same issue here

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek my case is that i unzip hadoop tarball into the user's home directory, say /home/hadoop, and I set hdfs's data directory a subfolder of the home dir. And I also enabled encrypted disk feature of ubuntu. so in this case, when all logged in sessions of user 'hadoop' are disconnected, the user's home directory would become unreachable, so hdfs cannot reach its data directory, hence the error. solution is to relocate hdfs binaries and set its data directory somewhere else. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your notes. I have identified the problem already. My Hadoop was entering safe mode because of high disk usage. I couldn't figure out why does it happen since every time I did `df -h` there was more than enough space. So I wrote a small script and added to the crontab. It turned out that the Hadoop has indeed low disk space because of backup job which is running every day at night and from time to time the disk usage was jumping up to 99%. I can't believe that the reason was so simple and I have missed that :P Anyway, Hadoop was right to enter safe mode ;P